# Making the analogy of finiteness and compactness precise

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, compactness

If one asks about the intution behind compact topological spaces, most often one will hear the mantra

> “Compactness of a topological space is a generalisation of the finiteness of a set.”

For example, every real-valued function on a finite set is bounded, whereas any continuous, real-valued function on a compact topological space is bounded. (The converse is only true for [pseudocompact spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space)).

Thinking categorically, this analogy could be made precise by finding a general definition of compactness in a suitable category. This should result in the compact objects of $\textbf{Set}$ being the finite sets and the compact objects of $\textbf{Top}$ being the compact topological spaces.

In the category $\textbf{Set}$ one can phrase finiteness in the following way:

> A set is finite if and only if every monomorphism on the set is also an epimorphism.

However, when generalised to $\textbf{Top}$ this does not work, since monomorphisms/epimorphisms in $\textbf{Top}$ are in particular injective/surjective and so we only get finite topological spaces. Incidentally, in $\textbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{k}}$ we get finite-dimensional vector spaces, which seems fitting.

*Question*: It is often said that the category $\textbf{Top}$ is not very well behaved. Is there a replacement of $\textbf{Top}$ or some better categorical way which makes the analogy of finiteness and compactness precise?

*Disclaimer*:
I know that there is the notion of a [compact object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object) of a general category, however this does not result in a correct characterisation of compactness in $\textbf{Top}$ and so does not seem to fully capture the desired analogy.

Comment: In my mind, one of the most important aspects of compactness is that a compact topology (in an abstract "pointless" sense) can be viewed as having been built from finite collections of open sets. For example, compact zero-dimensional Hausdorff spaces are precisely those that are inverse limits of finite discrete spaces. I don't know much category theory, but this feels to me like something that might generalize to other categories.

Comment: Your definition of finiteness is called Dedekind-finiteness; it is not what is used in Set Theory: "in bijection with a natural number". The two notions are equivalent under (some form) of the Axiom of Choice.
See [this paper](https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1960.11989538) by Edwin Hewitt for analogues between compactness and finiteness in Analysis

Comment: @KPHart However, one only needs something weaker than countable choice, so accepting Dedekind-finiteness as being equivalent to finiteness in the usual sense should not be very controversial. But you are right, if one only supposes ZF, one can have an infinite set with no countable subset.

Comment: @KPHart: In all fairness, before we talk about topology without choice, talking about topology in ZFC is probably fine. Having said that, it is true that if we want to work internally to $\bf Top$, where choice fails, it's worth being careful about these things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Choice or not: in practice when working with compactness one takes the finite subcover and enumerates it as $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ for some natural number $n$. I have yet to see an argument in topology or analysis where "every injection is a surjection" is used. So I'd say your analogy should take that aspect into account as well.